# Flex relative to outer div (position will not help)

Tags: css, flexbox

What I want to do is align .prod (products) all next to each other as if they were actually in the .subcontainer.

I can't use position since the 8th prod will not sit next to the 9th prod and so on.  I could write some JS to do this however I'm trying to use pure css/sass.  I have a feeling it's not possible, therefore stackoverflow amaze me with your work arounds.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/shaggywolfhound/pen/vYpMaPx
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="subcontainer">
    <ol class="prod-cont">
      <li class="prod"></li>
      <li class="prod"></li>
      <li class="prod"></li>
      <li class="prod"></li>
      <li class="prod"></li>
      <li class="prod"></li>
      <li class="prod"></li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="prod-cont">
      <li class="prod"></li>
      <li class="prod"></li>
.....
```

SASS:

```
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 2000px;
  
  .subcontainer {
    border: 1px solid red;
    
    .prod-cont {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      
      .prod {
        margin: 2px;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid green;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 45px;
        height: 100px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say 'next to each other' do you want 4 vertical lists next to each other (or however many ols there are in the real case) or do you want each product to be on the same line as the previous one, until there is not more room and a new row is started?

Comment: Each product to be on the same line as the previous one, until there is no more room and a new row is started.

Comment: Need to stay in order so not columns, must read left to right.  I have added numbers to the .prod containers.

Answer (score 1):

just add `display: flex` on `.subcontainer` and `padding-left: 0` on `.prod-cont`.

Your code should look like this:

```
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 2000px;
  
  .subcontainer {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid red;
    
    .prod-cont {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      padding-left: 0;
      
      .prod {
        margin: 2px;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid green;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 45px;
        height: 100px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wish I had tried harder to fix this now.  Honestly didn't expect that to work.  Thank you!

Comment: Sorry just realised this puts them into columns but I need them to be in the original order.  So as if you were to read the page like a book.  I've updated the codepen.